# Apache/Tomcat/mod_jk. How to make several urls to point to different tomcat instances?

Tags: apache, tomcat, dns, mod-jk

**My case:** 
I have several webapps running on my tomcat server like this: 
demo.myserver.com/application1
demo.myserver.com/application2
demo.myserver.com/application3

**This is what I want:** 
Application1.mydomain.com to point to demo.myserver.com/application1
Application2.mydomain.com to point to demo.myserver.com/application2
Application3.mydomain.com to point to demo.myserver.com/application3

**This is what I have done:**
1.  I have set my DNS server to point Application1.mydomain.com and so on to my servers IP address.
2.  I have set up apache webserver, apache tomcat6 and the JK2 plugin to make them communicate.

3.  I have configured a virtual domain for all my domains in httpd-vhosts.conf and enabled it in httpd.conf.

**httpd.conf:**

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName Application1.mydomain.com
JkMount /* workername
</VirtualHost>
```

4.  I have verified that everything works fine with just apache.

My problem is when I try to use the JKMount to redirect the requests to my application. How can I do this? Or is it a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried three different workernames?

Comment: The thing about the workers is that they are used for load-balancing. Therefor you can only have one per Tomcat instance I think. So using multiple workers won't help me unless I use one instance for each webapp. Please correct me if I am wrong.